# React useState hook value does not update in a custom tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am writing a simple React project testing the lightbox effect using `react-photoswipe-gallery`. I wrote the `onWheel` function to implement image zoom in/out on mouse scroll. This function worked just fine for the `<div>` outside the `<Gallery>` tag.

However, the same code does not work for the `<div>` within the `<Gallery>` tag. I inspected both images inside and outside the `<Gallery>` tag, while the outside `${pos}` changes on mouse scroll, the one inside the `<Gallery>` remain to ne the initial value.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Gallery, Item } from 'react-photoswipe-gallery';
import 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css';

function FavoriteColor() {

  const [pos, setPos] = useState(1);

  const onWheel = (event) => {
    const deltaY = event.deltaY;
    const scaleFactor = 0.1;

    setPos(prevScale => {
      let newScale = prevScale;

      if (deltaY < 0) {
        newScale += scaleFactor;
      } else {
        newScale -= scaleFactor;
      }
      return newScale;
    });

  };


  console.log(pos);
  return (
    <div>
      <div onWheel={onWheel}>
        <img src='https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg' style={{
          transformOrigin: "0 0",
          transform: `scale(${pos})`
        }} />
      </div>

      <Gallery >
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'grid',
            gridTemplateColumns: '240px 171px 171px',
            gridTemplateRows: '114px 114px',
            gridGap: 12,
          }}
        >
          <Item
            content={
              <div onWheel={onWheel}>
                <img className={pos} src='https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg' style={{
                  transformOrigin: "0 0",
                  transform: `scale(${pos})`
                }} />
              </div>}
          >

            {({ ref, open }) => (
              <img
                style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg"
                ref={ref}
                onClick={open}
              />
            )}
          </Item>
        </div>
      </Gallery>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<FavoriteColor />);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace onWheelCapture with onWheel on the div element. This will allow the scroll event to propagate to the child img element as well.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Gallery, Item } from 'react-photoswipe-gallery';
import 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css';

function FavoriteColor() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");

  const smallItemStyles = {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    // objectFit: 'cover',  // Try changing to 'contain'
    width: '100%',
    maxHeight: '100%',
  };

  const [pos, setPos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1 });

  const onWheel = (e) => {
    const delta = e.deltaY * -0.01;
    const newScale = pos.scale + delta;

    const ratio = 1 - newScale / pos.scale;

    setPos({
      scale: newScale,
      x: pos.x + (e.clientX - pos.x) * ratio,
      y: pos.y + (e.clientY - pos.y) * ratio
    });
    console.log('test');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Gallery>
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'grid',
            gridTemplateColumns: '240px 171px 171px',
            gridTemplateRows: '114px 114px',
            gridGap: 12,
          }}
        >
          <Item
          content={<div onWheel={onWheel}>  {/* Use onWheel here */}
              <img style={{ ...smallItemStyles, objectFit: 'contain' }}  {/* Add objectFit style to img */}
              src='https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg'/></div>}
          >
            {({ ref, open }) => (
              <img
                style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg"
                ref={ref}
                onClick={open}
              />
            )}
          </Item>
          {/* Other Item components */}
        </div>
      </Gallery>

    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<FavoriteColor />);
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not seem to work. I changed it to onWheel it is still not responsive.

Comment: Hey, I've made a few changes in code, check now. If issue remains then try to inspect component.,

Comment: It still does not work. I tested the onWheel code on a regular div without putting it in the lightbox tag, and it worked fine. What should I check when inspecting component?

Comment: inspect the rendered HTML of the <div> and <img> elements within the Lightbox component. Look for any inline styles that might be overriding the zooming behavior.

Comment: I did some further test and updated my question.  There is not any inline styling. Somehow the hook does not seem to work in the Gallery tag, don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Gallery, Item } from 'react-photoswipe-gallery';
import 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css';

function FavoriteColor() {

  const [pos, setPos] = useState(1);

  const onWheel = (event) => {
    const deltaY = event.deltaY;
    const scaleFactor = 0.1;

    setPos(prevScale => {
      let newScale = prevScale;

      if (deltaY < 0) {
        newScale += scaleFactor;
      } else {
        newScale -= scaleFactor;
      }
      return newScale;
    });

  };

  console.log(pos);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onWheel={onWheel}>
        <img src='https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg' style={{
          transformOrigin: "0 0",
          transform: `scale(${pos})`
        }} />
      </div>

      <Gallery onWheel={onWheel}>
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'grid',
            gridTemplateColumns: '240px 171px 171px',
            gridTemplateRows: '114px 114px',
            gridGap: 12,
          }}
        >
          <Item
            content={
              <div>
                <img className={pos} src='https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg' style={{
                  transformOrigin: "0 0",
                  transform: `scale(${pos})`
                }} />
              </div>}
          >

            {({ ref, open }) => (
              <img
                style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg"
                ref={ref}
                onClick={open}
              />
            )}
          </Item>
        </div>
      </Gallery>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<FavoriteColor />);
```

Comment: I think something intercepted onWheel event.

Comment: This above code still does not change the scale of the <div> in the Gallery. How can I find if anything intercepted the event?

Comment: It's just my opinion. Maybe in Gallery or other components in page will intercept, I think. Look around other components of your page

Comment: As I print the value of $pos, its value does change, so I suppose the onWheel still works fine? However, the scale in the <img> tag just does not change.

Comment: Try another way. 
<Item
            content={
              <div onWheel={onWheel}>
                <img className={pos} src='https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg' style={{
                  transformOrigin: "0 0",
                  transform: `scale(${pos})`
                }} />
              </div>}
            onWheel={onWheel} // Pass the onWheel event handler to Item component
          >

and then remove onWheel = {onWheel} in my previous code

Comment: Still no luck..

Comment: OMG. okay, just a moment.
I will send another modify code soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your willing to help. I think you may want to run it in a React project to see how it run. It is very strange, I don't know why the $pos changes perfectly when outside the <item> but does not change at all when being inside.

Comment: In your original code, insert onWheel = {onWheel} code to img tag.
And to prevent the default scrolling behavior when zooming in and out, add event.preventDefault() function to onWheel function

Comment: I've actually tried this. It emits a "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation." error.

Comment: I just found that the image does not zoom in the slide show mode. However, when I exit the slide show mode and reopen the slide show, the image will directly display with a the correct scale.

Comment: I am trying to find error and modify now.
I like to solve problem but this is very strange.
Let me check again.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const imgElement = document.querySelector('.zoomable-image');
    if (imgElement) {
      imgElement.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel, { passive: false });
    }
    return () => {
      if (imgElement) {
        imgElement.removeEventListener('wheel', onWheel);
      }
    };
  }, []);

try to add this code

Comment: You mean add this line of code directly to the code you posted? It still does not work..

Comment: Delete above code and try like this.
Add OnWheel = OnWheel() code to Item tag and then insert preventdefault().
There will be no error.

Comment: So, based on the code you posted, I remove the onWheel={onWheel} from the <Gallery> and <div> tag, and added it to the <item> tag. I then added the useEffect( ) code in your comments. and added event.preventDefault( ) to the onWheel function.    It still remains the same, when in slideshow mode, the image does not response to mouse scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257207/discussion-between-samtest-and-chester-reynolds).